# Compute statics for deleted partition in hive 1.2.1

Tags: hive, presto

I have a functionality where I want to delete data from partition. If all the data is deleted then remove the partition as well. 
Below are the steps we are found:

- Search for data for the partition which is based on date.
- Delete the data from partition
- Check if any records are present if present performs compute statistics. For columns as well.
- If there are no records delete the partition and perform compute statistics.

When we perform a select query, it is showing me the error for deleted partition.
Even if we call compute statistics, still it is showing that partition does not exist.
Do I miss anything?

We have tried to compute the statistics with some code changes but it won't work. Below are the steps we are following:

If partition deleted then below are the next 2 steps we are following:

```
ALTER TABLE transactions DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (eventday=" + eventDay + ")
ALTER TABLE transactions ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (eventday=" + eventDay + ")
```

These steps are executed every time:

```
ANALYZE TABLE transactions PARTITION(eventday=" + eventDay + ") COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS
ANALYZE TABLE transactions PARTITION(eventday=" + eventDay + ") COMPUTE STATISTICS
```

The expected result is to avoid this exception as the partition is not available 
but for a select query for delete partition, it is showing this error.

> java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20190619_060000_00416_bztpj): Partition location does not exist: hdfs://XXXX/XX/XX

Comment: Why not simply delete partition and data?